# Generate all de Bruijn sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algorithms, hamiltonian-path

There are [several methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348673/3163618) to generate a de Bruijn sequence. Is there a general algorithm to create all unique (rotations are counted as the same) De Bruijn sequences for a binary alphabet of length $n$, or $B(2, n)$?

For example, one such sequence for $B(2, 5)$ is $00000111011010111110011000101001$.

Comment: The fact that the sequences are finite and that determining whether a sequence is "De Bruijn" is computable means that the answer is trivially "yes such an algorithm exists".  As far as computation speed goes, even generating 1 Debruijn sequence is exponentially oppressive, generating them all is probably doubly exponentially space consuming, so asking for a tractable algorithm is almost absurd afaik.

Comment: @DanielV I meant for a small given $n$, like $5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small $n$, a depth-first search using a list or set of "already seen" subsequences does the trick.

Edit: Here is the code I wrote in 2015-2016 (I would write it differently now). It included one of my "clever tricks" where since the lexicographically first string of a particular cyclic sequence starts with $n$ zeros, if there are equal counts of zeros and ones, then all substrings (including the wraparound ones) are included, obviating the need for string rotations.

```
# De Bruijn sequences return...
# Generate strings using DFS, ignoring strings with "seen" subsequences

def S(arrange, seen, N):
    # len(arrange) can be removed if 00000 is marked as seen
    if len(arrange) == 2**N and 2*arrange.count(0) == 2**N:
        print(''.join(map(str, arrange)))

    for c in (0, 1):
        new_seen = seen[:]
        new_arrange = arrange + [c]

        word = ''.join(map(str, new_arrange[-N:]))
        seen_i = int(word, 2)

        if not new_seen[seen_i]:
            new_seen[seen_i] = 1
            S(new_arrange, new_seen, N)


S([0]*5, [0]*2**5, 5)  # Beginning must be 00000
```

Comment: I added [a basic de Bruijn graph algorithm in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/27e145248b3baa2e6331d25b831241b8#file-debruijn-graph-js-L14-L16) (with results in the comment below), using DFS as you described, but it doesn't always give de Bruijn sequences. Can you point me to what I should be doing differently?

Comment: @Lance it has been a long time since I have written this code. You can ask as a separate question on StackOverflow and link it here but I can't guarantee I remember the details.

Comment: I'm not that fluent in JS yet and idk where my original code is but I almost certainly wrote it recursively rather than with an explicit stack (shouldn't really matter for small inputs) and I don't think I generated every bit permutation (actually I'm not sure what that does)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have made it into an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950434/how-to-generate-all-de-bruijn-sequences-using-de-bruijn-graphs-in-javascript). Hoping to see how to generate all the sequences .

Comment: Are you sure it can generate all of them? Maybe you can update this current answer on Math SE with more detail. Because I don't see how it can generate all of them, like long stretches of length-3 substrings, etc..

Comment: @Lance I dug through my old code and I've added it here so you can peer into my 2015 mind. Sorry I didn't look through your code very much.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you add a little bit more comment to the code ?   I could not understand your code, is it related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem ?

Comment: @kevin no, like I said it's just DFS.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by **if there are equal counts of zeros and ones, then all substrings (including the wraparound ones) are included, obviating the need for string rotations.** ?

Comment: if DFS reaches 32 characters in the string and equal counts of zeros and ones are in the string, then wraparound strings don't need to be checked since they will all end in zeros

Comment: What is the purpose of the condition : `2*arrange.count(0) == 2**N` ?

Comment: Besides, what is the purpose of one other condition: `if not new_seen[seen_i]` ?

Comment: Those count equal zeros and ones like I said and the other is a basic DFS condition to recurse. (If you have more questions it's probably more appropriate for Stack Overflow then this math site on the programming. Maybe my variable naming at the time wasn't the best.)

Comment: Thanks, I had just opened up [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72946272/understand-the-code-for-generation-of-all-de-bruijn-sequences) for the coding questions

Comment: by the way, what do you think about [Sawada and Ruskey method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4078191/6422632) and the [other implementations](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2014-February/068770.html) ?

Comment: @kevin I've never looked at them since I found my solution was sufficient

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The approach which finds an Eulerian cycle of an $(n-1)$-dimensional graph is easily adapted to find all Eulerian cycles starting at a given vertex. Since rotating a sequence corresponds to tracing the same Eulerian cycle but starting at a different vertex, this adaptation generates exactly one representative for each equivalence class of sequences. In fact, you can even easily make it enumerate them in lexicographic order.

Comment: Do you know of an algorithm/method that can produce De Bruijn graphs and traces Eulerian paths?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Constructing_Eulerian_trails_and_circuits

Comment: Seems to me DFS would work also, what do you think?

Comment: @qwr, DFS as typically described in algorithms text visits each edge only once and each node only twice. I can see how tracing an Eulerian path could be thought of as both depth-first and a search, but to call it DFS is to invite confusion. And to generate all Eulerian cycles you need to backtrack.

Comment: I am describing a DFS approach that builds the string up, entirely skipping the whole Eulerian path idea

Comment: I added [a basic de Bruijn graph algorithm in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/27e145248b3baa2e6331d25b831241b8#file-debruijn-graph-js-L14-L16) (with results in the comment below), but it doesn't always give de Bruijn sequences. Any suggestions on what should be different?

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating Eulerian cycles is the way to go. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23543435/18691245) gives an algorithm in $\mathcal{O}(P(E)N)$ where $P$ is polynomial and $N$ is the number of Eulerian cycles.

Here is a more efficient algorithm :
Choose a vertex $v$ and enumerate all directed spanning trees (with edges pointing toward the root) rooted at $v$ ([It can be done in $\mathcal{O}(V + E + NE) = \mathcal{O}(NV)$](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Finding-All-Spanning-Trees-of-Directed-and-Graphs-Gabow-Myers/1e6def70ffee749fc3f5889e3dedb3184044d02d) where $N$ is the number of rooted spanning tree) because $E = \mathcal{O}(V)$ for de Bruijn graphs). Find a cycle through the graph by starting at $v$. At each vertex you cross, choose some leaving edge you never took, and never take the edge going back to its parent on the tree **before** taking every other edge leaving this vertex. Enumerate all the cycles you find like this by taking all the possible choices at every vertex. This can be done in $\mathcal{O}(NV)$, where $N$ is the number of Eulerian cycles.

At the end, you should find every possible Eulerian cycle in an optimal time.

Take all cyclic permutations of all Eulerian cycle to get all the de Bruijn sequences.

This algorithm is based on the [BEST theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem) for the enumeration of Eulerian cycles.

Answer (score 0):

De Bruijn sequences are a subset of all the permutations.  So, generate all the permutations in order, and check for their satisfaction of de Bruijn requirements.  That alone will generate all examples B(k,n) for any k and n.  The time profile for algorithm halting is a completely different question.

Comment: What do you mean by permutation? If you mean a string of length 32, that is essentially brute force.

Comment: Yes, it is a brute-force method that I suggest.